# Python function that is supposed to take a certain file and print out the occurrences of a certain part of the file

Tags: python, file, function

1. For example, if I take this file: http://vlm1.uta.edu/~athitsos/courses/cse1310_summer2013/assignments/assignment7/albums.txt
   I need the function to count each band and the number of times they are listed in the file and print it on screen in descending order.
2. It should be in this format
   band1: number1
   band2: number2
   band3: number3
3. this is what I have so far:

   ```
   def read_albums(filename):


       counter = 0
       work_list = []
       my_file = open(filename, 'r')
       for line in my_file:
           my_list = line.split()
           work_list = line.split()

       for i in range(0, len(my_list)):
           item = my_list[0]
           counter = 1
           j = i + 1
           for j in range(j, len(my_list)):
                   if j > len(my_list):
                           j = len(my_list)        
                   if item == my_list[0]:
                           counter = counter + 1
                           work_list[j] = None
                   else:
                           continue
           if work_list[0] != None:
                   print(work_list[0], counter)
   ```
4. Any tips regarding what I am doing wrong would be very helpful, I just cant seem to get it

Comment: you have a whole lot wrong ... not even sure where to start. ..

Answer (score 2):

```
d = defaultdict(int)
with open("some_file.txt") as f:
     for line in file:
         artist,album = line.split("-")
         d[artist] += 1

for k,v in d.items():
    print "%s:%s"%(k,v)
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would be the Pythonic way to go:

```
from collections import Counter

with open('albums.txt') as f:
    print Counter(line.split(' - ')[0] for line in f)
```

I recommend you take look at [this](http://pyvideo.org/video/1758) talk.

Comment: thats better than my answer I think

Comment: well your output is more correct but I thought I would leave him some work to do, :-)

Answer (score 0):

You already have a working answer so I will just say where you went wrong.

```
my_list = line.split()
work_list = line.split()
```

They are exactly the same so I'll just stick with work_list.

```
work_list = line.split()
```

This splits the text at each space, so "Pink Floyd - Album" will become ["Pink", "Floyd", "-", "Album"]. Also, what it does is it sets the variable work_list to the latest line you split. What you want is to put all the split lines in a list:

```
work_list.append(line.split("-")[0])
```

This splits the line properly and only returns the first element, which is the band name. This is then appended to the list work_list, which you have properly initialised as empty at the beginning.

Once you have the bands in a list, you can use any method to count all the occurrances. Counter is brilliant for that. Your method had a lot of logic flaws, but I think what you were going for was (in pseudocode):

```
for each item in the array (item)
    go through all the remaining items (new_item)
        if item == new_item
            increase counter
```

This doesn't count the occurances of each item once. For example, every time it comes across a band, it will count all the duplicate ones from that point forward. What you would want instead is a set, which is like a list but with no duplicate entries.

```
work_set = set(work_list)

for band in work_set:
    counter = 0
    for i in range(len(work_list)):
        if work_list[i] == band:
            counter += 1
    print (band, counter)
```

If your programs don't behave as expected, you can print your variables to see whether they are assigned what you expect them to.